# AngularJS subsequent $http deletes stay in pending for minutes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have a table which displays a list of objects, and each of those objects is associated with an arbitrary number of child objects. I'm using Angular 1.2.20, Express 4.6.1, and Node 0.10.25. The table has a "remove" button which invokes two API calls that:

1) Delete the selected object
2) Delete the child objects associated with the selected object

The first remove works just fine--the two API calls return DELETE 200 quickly. However, subsequent removal attempts on the table result in the API calls not returning for several minutes in Chrome and Firefox. Safari seems to work perfectly fine, strangely enough. If I continue to attempt removing more table items, then the page stops responding to any input until I do a browser refresh. I can see the requests in $http.pendingRequests fill up, and they're not flushed until several minutes later, and even then they're flushed in small batches.

It's as though angularjs isn't letting go of the initial API calls, which causes subsequent API calls to back up. Not sure why this works in Safari but not Chrome or Firefox. The API is just ExpressJS with MongoDB, but even if I just implement an empty ExpressJS controller function for the delete calls, the problem still persists:

```
exports.delete = function(req, res) {
    /*FormDistributionGroup.remove({_id: req.params.distGroupId},
        function(err, distGroup) {
            if(err) {
                return res.json(500, err);
        } else {
            return res.json(distGroup);
        }
    });*/
    return res.json({});
}
```

Here is the view code for the "remove" button:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="removeDistsByGroup(distGroup._id)">Remove</button>
```

Here is the controller code for the "remove" button:

```
$scope.removeDistsByGroup = function(distGroupId) {
            var promises = [];
            promises.push(FormDistributionGroupService.delete(distGroupId));
            promises.push(FormDistributionService.deleteByDistGroupId(distGroupId));
            $q.all(promises).then(function() {
                window.alert("Successfully removed distribution group.");
                $scope.distGroupList = $scope.distGroupList.filter(function(distGroup) {
                    return distGroup._id != distGroupId;
                });
            });
        }
```

Here are the two associated service functions that are invoked by the controller:

FormDistributionService:

```
        deleteByDistGroupId: function(groupDistId) {
            return $http.delete(distributeJsonPath + '/group-dist/' + groupDistId).then(function(res) {
                return res.data;
            });
        }
```

FormDistributionGroupService:

```
        delete: function(id) {
            return $http.delete(distributeJsonPath + '/' + id).then(function(res) {
                return res.data;
            });
        },
```

Comment: This only seems to be an issue for DELETE requests to the Express API. If I bind the button click to consecutive GET requests, the response is returned promptly.

Comment: Even more curious--this only seems to happen on OS X browsers:
OS: OS X 10.9.5
Firefox version: 34.0.5
Chrome version: 39.0.2171.95

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with deferred objects, you will want to return the correct chain of events with each method. 
Take a look at the angular docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

It *could* probably look something like:

```
deleteByDistGroupId: function(groupDistId) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.delete(distributeJsonPath + '/group-dist/' + groupDistId).then(function(res) {
        deferred.resolve(res.data);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}


delete: function(id) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.delete(distributeJsonPath + '/' + id).then(function(res) {
         deferred.resolve(res.data);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
},
```

Comment: That didn't seem to change how the application responds to consecutive deletes. Angular still gets hung up after a few deletes, and then stops responding entirely. Netstat shows 6 connections from Angular to Express. I should mention I'm using the MEAN.io stack, and even their Articles package suffers the same issue, so maybe it's something with their stuff. I filed an issue with them: github.com/linnovate/mean/issues/987

Answer (score 0):

Using $timeout with a deferred promise seems to help, but that's just cancelling the promise.

This seems to significantly help:

```
remove: function(id) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.delete(distributeJsonPath + '/' + id, {timeout : deferred.promise}).then(function(res) {
                return res.data;
            });
            $timeout(function() {
                deferred.resolve();
            }, 5000);
        },
```

I think the underlying problem is still there though.